# What does && mean with a parameter type in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, c++11, rvalue-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does T&& mean in C++0x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-mean-in-c0x)

I had never seen a double ampersand before I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3731357/674683).

The code snippet in question is this:

```
template <typename T>
T& as_lvalue(T&& x)
{
    return x;
}
```

What does `&&` achieve?  What sorts of parameters can be passed to `as_lvalue()`

Comment: Some context would be useful in the title - I came here expecting a discussion of logical operators.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is called an [rvalue reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rvalue_reference#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors), and it is new in C++11. It binds to temporaries without making a copy.

Comment: that doesn't really answer the question -- I have lots of experience in C++ prior to this new standard and my eyes just glaze over when I read the wikipedia page.

Comment: The [MSDN article on the rvalue operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293668.aspx) is more extensive than that Wikipedia link.

Comment: @JasonS: It binds to temporaries without making a copy

Answer (score 0):

Most common usage is short-circuit boolean and operator.

C++11 uses it for rvalue references. Your example uses that.